# What is כף הכינוי?

Tags: minhag, words, prayer-book, yekke

In R' Wiesenthal's [Siddur Sefas Yisroel](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47352&st=&pgnum=19&hilite=), he talks about the כף הכינוי and different opinions about it. But I have no idea what this actually is. So, what is 
כף הכינוי?

Comment: It seems to be that he's talking about the word לך being vowelized either ָלְך or ְלָך, but I can't explain the name "כף הכינוי"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the suffixed ך used to indicate a second-person direct object or possessor. Thus it's a כף (the letter of the alphabet) of כינוי (i.e. referring to someone or something).